# Unable to connect docker aerospike server using c# client

Tags: c#, docker, aerospike

I'm new to aerospike.
I have deployed aerospike using Docker.
Below is the command that I have used to deploy the Aerospike server.

```
docker run -d --name aerospike1 -p 3000:3000 aerospike/aerospike-server
```

docker ps output :

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                   NAMES
1376791119a2        aerospike/aerospike-server   "/entrypoint.sh asd"   13 minutes ago      Up 13 minutes       0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp, 3001-3003/tcp   aerospike1
```

However, while connecting I'm getting a connection error.

Error :

> Error -8: Failed to connect to host(s):  localhost 3000 Error -8: A
>   connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly
>   respond after a period of time, or established connection failed
>   because connected host has failed to respond

Below is my code

```
            // Establish connection the server
            AerospikeClient client = new AerospikeClient("localhost",3000);

            // Create key
            Key key = new Key("test", "credits", "123425");
            //Key key = new Key("test", "foo", "123");

            // Create Bins
            Bin bin1 = new Bin("name", "Sam");
            Bin bin2 = new Bin("age", 25);
            Bin bin3 = new Bin("gender", "Male");
            Bin bin4 = new Bin("department", "Engineering");

            // Write record
            client.Put(null, key, bin1, bin2, bin3, bin4);

            // Read record
            Record record = client.Get(null, key);
            string s = record.GetGeoJSON("");
            // Close connection
            client.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: What is your host operating system? Windows has some issues with port forwarding  and localhost in docker. Try connecting directly to the container IP see if it works.

Comment: @YamaçKurtuluş I'm using windows.
I have tried connecting to a container IP address which is also giving connection error.

Comment: I would use a sniffer like wireshark of fiddler to capture request and response.  Check what the status code is for the response to get clue for the cause. I would check to see if you are using http 1.0 (stream mode) or http 1.1 (chunk mode).  Often timeouts occur because you are using 1.1 which requires sending a "Next Chunk" after each chunk is received.  When you do not send the next chunk message a timeout occurs.

Comment: I used your docker command as is linux. I am able to connect to the server from outside the docker. (I am using c-client, but it should not matter). I am not sure what else may be going on in windows.

Comment: @sunil I'm using windows.
I still didn't find any solution for this.

Comment: Are you running docker directly in windows ? Or you have a VM and running docker inside that ? As @YamaçKurtuluş mentioned, windows seems to have issues with port forwarding. Were you able to use any non-aerospike service with port forwarding in docker ? I am guessing that window firewall may be blocking things. May be you can by temporarily disabling the firewall.

Comment: Also try this: 
`docker run -d --name aerospike1 --hostname aerospike1 -p 3000:3000 aerospike/aerospike-server`

then try accessing to `http://aerospike1:3000`

Additionally, just checking: you tried <containerIpAddress>:3000 right? With the port number and not only the IP